# Do beta users in Google Play receive updates from the production channel?

Tags: android, google-play

I am actually new to Google Play as a developer, and, till today, I have released my apps only under the production track.

I have one question regarding the beta (open testing) track: Do beta users receive updates from the production track?

Comment: @SimonMarquis Thanks, that answers the question. Could post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, beta users will receive the production app update if the version code is greater than the beta version.

> All users are always eligible to receive the production track. If an APK with a higher version code is published in production than in the test track where the user opted in, the user will receive the production APK.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en#version_codes